# Winform: cant control any buttons or UI elements with Pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

Inspect Output:

```
How found:  Selected from tree...
Name:   "Install Service"
ControlType:    UIA_ButtonControlTypeId (0xC350)
LocalizedControlType:   "button"
BoundingRectangle:  {l:819 t:599 r:920 b:622}
IsEnabled:  true
IsOffscreen:    false
IsKeyboardFocusable:    true
HasKeyboardFocus:   false
AccessKey:  ""
ProcessId:  5924
RuntimeId:  [2A.1A50414]
AutomationId:   "btnInstallSvc"
FrameworkId:    "WinForm"
ClassName:  "WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1"
NativeWindowHandle: 0x1A50414
ProviderDescription:    "[pid:18028,providerId:0x1A50414 Main:Nested [pid:5924,providerId:0x1A50414 Main(parent link):Microsoft: MSAA Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]; Hwnd(parent link):Microsoft: HWND Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]"
IsPassword: false
HelpText:   ""
```

Error: `pywintypes.error: (1400, 'GetWindowRect', 'Invalid window handle.')`

Comment: This is known [issue #534](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/534). You can try to rollback to `pywinauto==0.6.4` so far.

Comment: Thank you Vasily, Can I control winforms application developed using .Net Framework

Comment: Sure, all .NET apps are supported by “uia” backend. Find Getting Started Guide for the details about available backends.